# I get sound but no images/graphics on Minecraft 1.7.10 on Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

I downloaded Minecraft 1.7.10 on Ubuntu 64 bit platform for my son. I was told double click on Minecraft.jar in order to start the program however executable bit was missing and when I double clicked on it, the file opened up displaying folders and files. It was more like a zip file instead of executable file I expected.

I tried the command `java -jar Minecraft.jar` instead at command line after adding x bit on it. The program started fine, however in the end I can only hear sound but no images whatsoever. Has anyone come across this before? I wonder what I did wrong. I'd appreciate your help on this.

[update]

I ran into an article saying that go to properties of minecraft.jar and check on allow executing file as program under permissions and make sure open with OpenJDK instead of archive manager. Now I don't have to run java command. However that didn't fix no images problem. I wonder if I need to replace graphics card and get appropriate driver...the laptop I use is 5 years old HP Pavilion dv7-1245dx.

Comment: The`.jar` (Java Archive) is a form of `.zip` file. Running this will not run Minecraft in the way it was expected - hence your perceived issues. You will need to try and find some form of `.exe` to run instead (I believe there is now an installer?)

Comment: Not exe, its on linux, go to minecraft.net and download the launcher

Comment: Try to uninstall and re-install java

Comment: The official sites says to use Oracle JVM, whereas you are using OpenJDK.

Comment: Will try with Oracle JDK. Thank you for your input.

Comment: removed openjdk and installed oracle jdk 7 but the problem is still persistent...

Comment: @DaeYoung Try looking at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/198476/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution/), it's a tutorial of how to install Minecraft on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system requirements are outdated. I apologize for this inconvenience, but, I've looked at system specs for your Pavilion, and determined it's outdated. You could update the GPU with an [external graphics card](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=&cs=04&sku=A7057588&dgc=ST&cid=293344&lid=5616479&acd=12309152537461010&ven1=sE1inYhPj&ven2=,), but, you should just buy a new laptop. [My laptop PC](http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-15.6-15-F039WM-Laptop-PC-with-Intel-Celeron-N2830-Processor-4GB-Memory-500GB-Hard-Drive-and-Windows-8.1-Black/38043712), which has hits a smooth 48-60+ FPS, is very cheap, considering the cooling system, the portability, and the excellent performance of Windows 8.1 (Ignore the hate.)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As you stated, I realized that my laptop was old and the graphic card couldn't handle the stream. I switched to another computer relatively new and the game was playing just fine.